# HttpClient Angular POST fails with Google FCM Server, how do I fix?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to successfully send FCM messages via a POST and HTTP v1 Firebase API to my app using Postman but when I use the same POST in Angular HttpRequest it fails:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCwQz.png)

Here are my imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Here is my code in the service:

```
sendFCMMessage(accessToken : string, data: object) {
console.log('sendFCMMessage');
console.log(accessToken);
console.log(data);

const authString : string = 'Bearer '+ accessToken;
console.log(authString);
const url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***-notifications/messages:send';
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  'Authorization': authString
})};

const body =
    {
    "message":{
  "token":"wwrwjeriwe8***",
  "notification":{
    "body":"The Knicks are winning!",
    "title":"Sports App"
    }
   }
};

return this.http.post(url,body,httpOptions).pipe(map(res => res));
}
```

I then subscribe to the response and get the error pasted above. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix? I am able to send FCM messages perfectly in Postman using the same exact POST  url, body and header.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Http response status code 401 means unauthorized, so it seems that your bearer token header is not present in your request.

```
    return this.http.post<any>(
      url,
      {
        message: {
          token: 'wwrwjeriwe8***',
          notification: {
            body: 'The Knicks are winning!',
            title: 'Sports App',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': authString,
        },
      }
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I do include the token in the const authString : string = 'Bearer '+ accessToken; Any other ideas? I was able to get this working by putting the Firebase Admin SDK in my backend server but was wondering why it doesn't work just via HttpRequest?

Comment: - Are you sure that the accessToken has no whitespaces at the end?

- Are your sure that the accessToken is valid and not expired? Print the accessToken, copy it and try to use this token in postman.

- Print the request and check if the header is present.

- Check the documentation. Maybe you have to send the json payload as "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded" (very unlikely but sometimes api endpoints can answer with wrong http errors)

Comment: Yes I did try all those things before posting this and the same request works fine in Postman like my original post says, thanks for the advice though. I think Google may have set it up so you cannot make these requests through the front end only through Firebase Admin SDK integrated into your server.

Comment: No, the Firebase Admin SDK also uses the same API under the hood. You can look into the source code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: To be more precisely: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/blob/8f1f9241c0b659bda59cf5ef2c08520bf109874d/messaging/index.js